# Using vim-surround with argument to a function

Tags: vim, repeat, vim-plugin, surround

I'm new to vim-surround. I would like to achieve the folowing.

I have an html file with many images as this (* is the cursor position):

```
<img src="ima*ges/pages/img1.jpg" alt="">
```

And I would like to change it with this:

```
<img src="{{ media_url('images/pages/img1.jpg') }}" alt="">
```

I tried `ys"f` but it doesn't work as expected. I would like to change all jpg images with such pattern, I'm aware of vim-repeat I will dig into it once I could change the first correctly.

If you know a way to achieve this to all jpg occurrences I would be really thankful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to record a macro and then execute on all images.

In normal mode position your cursor at first " start recording a macro with qq then:

cs"'va'hSbimedia_urlbvf)S{gvS}gvS"q

Now you have recorded a macro in q register. Execute it whit @q.

Position your self at next image(") and the @q. You can combine it with find (/"ima) then combine n and @q.

If you position yourself with find on next word while recording macro you can prefix macro with number ... 10@q execute it on 10 images....

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am trying your solution with one item to understand how it works, but when I arrive to the underline something seems to go wrong. When I type `cs"'va'hSb`, then I get <img src=('images/pages/img1.jpg') alt="">, however when I start typing `media_` as soon as I hit `_`, I get to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Sorry, missing i for insert before media. I was writing this from my head because I cannot paste q register content here, most special characters get eaten.

Comment: Thank you, now I have a similar problem but to leave insert mode and go back to the surround command. After I type `i` vim enters insert mode but how do I tell vim that this is actually part of the surround command? Perhaps the command must be spitted in two parts? I quite understand the first part `cs"'va'h`, not the rest.

Comment: That is the reason why i told you will have to record macro. You can read more about them here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I am a big fan of custom surroundings.

Example of a custom surrounding, by adding the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim`:

```
let b:surround_{char2nr('m')} = "{{ media_url('\r') }}"
```

Now in file's with the `FileType` of `html` you can use the `m` surrounding. It might be best to have 2 surroundings one for the curly braces and one for `media_url` function.

For more information see `:h surround-customizing`

Answer (score 0):

`:substitute` seems to be a better fit for this job:

```
:s#\v<img src="\zs\S{-}\.jpg\ze"#{{ media_url('\1') }}#g
```

If you don't want to change all of them, add `c` after the `g` to ask for user consent before each surrounding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I get `"Pattern not found: \v<img src="\zs\S{-}\.jpg\ze"`